# serverless azure functions cannot install on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

Trying to install serverless-azure-functions on Ubuntu 18 machine, but get the below error:

```
> keytar@4.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-azure-functions/node_modules/keytar
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-azure-functions/node_modules/keytar/build'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-azure-functions/node_modules/keytar/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless-azure-functions/node_modules/keytar
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Looks like a permission error?

I use the following command to install it:

```
sudo npm install serverless-azure-functions
```

Comment: Hi @Alvin did you get any further with this, i'm stuck with the same error.

Comment: This appears to be resolved in the latest version of the Azure Functions package.